# jquery-ui slider update value from code

Tags: jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

i've got a problem with updating slider value from code. i  have tried

```
$('#slider').slider('value', newValue);
$('#slider').val(newValue).slider();
$('#slider').val(newValue).slider('refresh');
```

and no result

any other suggestions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here is a sample code

> Determines the value of the slider, if
>   there's only one handle.  If there is
>   more than one handle, determines the
>   value of the first handle.

Code examples

```
Initialize a slider with the value option specified.
$( ".selector" ).slider({ value: 37 });
Get or set the value option, after init.
//getter
var value = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value", 37 );
```

Comment: Turned out that I had invalid selector.

Comment: @maxlego: Try this `$( "#slider" ).slider({ value: 37 });` to set slider value.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<input type="text" id="amount">
<input type="text" id="amount2">
<div id="slider-range"></div>
</html>
```

_

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 217,
    values: [ 0, 217 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] );
        $( "#amount2" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ] );
    }
});

$("#amount").change(function() {
    $("#slider-range").slider('values',0,$(this).val());
});
$("#amount2").change(function() {
    $("#slider-range").slider('values',1,$(this).val());
});

});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/brhuman/uvx6pdc1/

Answer (score -1):

Just call showSlider() which was in slider.js file wherever u want. It will automatically refresh.

Comment: From the question there's no evidence that the user is using slider.js